# URL amigavel Code igniter nao funciona

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-amigavel

meu htaccess dentro da pasta application esta assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

estou colocando na pasta certa? 
Codigo correto? aonde estou errando?

aguardo..

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que colocar na mesma pasta do index.php, fora do application. Já deve inclusive ter um .htaccess lá

Comment: Boa tarde Khaos, então já possuo um htaccess justamente aonde vc indicou, e possui o mesmo codigo q coloquei acima.. será que este codigo nao esteja funcionando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o .htacces deve ficar na pasta aonde está o site, se você tiver só 1 site na sua hospedagem use na pasta public_html ou www

Tente deixar assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Raphael, solucionou meu problema! Aprendi como funciona o Rewrite ! Obrigado!!!!